# How to revert a bricked chain due to bad setCode

Tags: consensus, grandpa, aura

I upgraded a chain that uses Grandpa/Aura with code for instant seal by mistake.
I believe it may be possible to revert some blocks:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/1479

But cannot find any documentation on how to do this. It is also asked here:
[How to unbrick a Substrate Chain? --revert?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-to-unbrick-a-substrate-chain-revert)

But no answer for how to use --revert is given.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `revert` command to revert unfinalized blocks. If you need to revert finalized blocks then I suggest you do the following:

- Assuming you want to revert to block #42;
- Add the hash of block #43 to the chain spec under `badBlocks` (example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/polkadot/a4931d93388688af2e39e1aca77a6dcefd4bbd10/node/service/chain-specs/kusama.json);
- Sync a node from scratch and it should stop importing blocks after #42 (since #43 is blacklisted it will fail to import);
- You can now deploy this database to other validators and they should start authoring (and finalizing on top of #42). Alternatively you can also just resync using the new chain spec;
- Since you are reverting finality all clients on the network will need to resync (using the new chainspec with `badBlocks` populated).

Comment: If this answered your question you should consider accepting the response :)

Answer (score 5):

I figured out how to revert some blocks:

```
./{chain executable} revert --base-path /home/ubuntu/chains --chain {chain name}--keep-blocks 351284 --pruning archive
```

For options:

```
./{chain executable} revert --help
```

Comment: Did it work? AFAIK this only reverts un-finalized blocks.